# Can't get this WHILE LOOP working in MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops, while-loop

I'm new to loops in Mysql and there doesn't seem to be that much info online about them. I have searched al over and can't get anything to work. Can anyone help with this please, this is the code

```
PROCEDURE while_loop()
  BEGIN

    SET @var_number_of_departments = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT departmentid) FROM employees); -- finds number of departments
    SET @var_departmentid = 1; -- sets incrementing value to 1

    WHILE @var_number_of_departments > @var_departmentid DO -- loop until all departments have been analyzed                            

      SELECT Name FROM employees WHERE BossID IS NULL AND departmentid =  @var_departmentid AND salary > (SELECT salary     FROM employees WHERE bossID IS NOT NULL    AND DepartmentID = @var_departmentid);

      SET @var_departmentid = @var_departmentid + '1'; -- increment value in order to analyze the next department

    end while;                           
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things that you can improve with your code:

1. The first line needs to start with `CREATE PROCEDURE`
2. You don't include a `DELIMITER` statement, so it won't run as is. Perhaps you've got a delimiter set elsewhere? if not, you'll need one.

To see how a basic `WHILE` loop might run, here's a simple example that doesn't use any SQL table queries:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE basic_while()
BEGIN
   SET @stopval := 5;
   SET @counter := 1;
   WHILE @counter <= @stopval DO
      SELECT @counter;
      SET @counter := @counter + 1;
   END WHILE;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Note the use of `DELIMITER` and the word `CREATE`.

Going further, some additional points that may help with this specific problem.

1. The loop over department IDs assumes that your department IDs are in a 1-based contiguous monotonically incrementing set. This is a big assumption. Consider what would happen if department IDs started at 1001, or if department 4 was merged into 6 so your deparments were 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7. Department 7 would never be counted.
2. You could solve this problem in a single query (with a nested subquery), which would give you a single resultset with all results rather than a resultset per department.
3. If you need to have a single resultset per department, consider using [cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html)
4. Your final `SET` line should not have quotes around the `1`, because you want to treat it as an integer. In this case it works, but it's a bad habit to get into.

Getting back to stored procedures, I'd recommend you spend some time going through the official syntax documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html, which contains a lot of this in authoritative form.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply that really has taught me some more stuff, much appreciated. I'm unsure whether this is now the best method.... My aim is to show any employees who have a higher wage than their boss. But this needs to be done for each department.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you think this answer is *correct*, then mark it as answered.